# How to notify all guard methods when global changes

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro

Often in my applications built with Caliburn Micro I have a need to store some global data; this could be app specific config, authentication properties, etc. I generally put them in a class called "Session" and inject that via constructor injection so that every view model has a reference to a single instance of Session.

I found a case where I wanted a guard method on two different view models to be linked to a Session variable; the issue is guard methods are generally notified of changes in the setter of the changed variable. Since it's a global, it doesn't know what depends on it. (It occurs to me that this pattern of variables being aware of what guard is hooked into them is bad, but when it's all in the same ViewModel it doesn't matter much.)

I could throw an event, but that's messy and a lot of work for something that should be simple.

I could try to identify every spot where it may have been updated and manually notify, but that's error prone.

```
public class MyViewModel: Screen{

  public MyViewModel(SessionInfo session){
    Session = session;
  }

  public CanTakeAction { get { return !string.isNullOrWhitespace(Session.SomeProperty); } }

}

public class SessionInfo {

  public SessionInfo(){}

  public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

  // this is where I would normally notify a guard method, but this is not going to work
  NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanTakeAction); // except it doesn't know about CanTakeAction
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to introduce a base ViewModel, which has the guard methods (virtual). For Example,

```
public class ViewModelBase:Screen
{
    private SessionInfo _sessionInfo;
    public ViewModelBase(SessionInfo sessionInfo)
    {
        _sessionInfo = sessionInfo;
    }

    public void NotifyGuardMethods()
    {
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(CanTakeAction));
    }
    public virtual bool CanTakeAction { get; set; } = false;
}
```

For all the ViewModels that needs to be notified by the change in Session, you could now derieve from the ViewModelBase.

```
public class ShellViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
        public override bool CanTakeAction { get=>//its own logic; set=>//its own logic; };
}
```

You could now introduce Events to the ViewModelBase, which could use the NotifyGuardMethods defined in the base class to notify all other view models. This ensures the messsy Events part would be restricted to one class alone (base view model).

Comment: This would work, but isn't quite what I'm looking for. The thing is, the actions are unique to the view models. Putting them in a base class just moves them from Session to a different class (albeit to a class that actually has knowledge of the guards via the virtuals); it doesn't solve having to know about all the places it is used, which is exactly the opposite of how a class should work (the class defines how it can be used, but doesn't care where it is used)